# Custom Vue JS plugin doesn't import correctly with Nuxt JS

Tags: vue.js, plugins, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I've build a Vue JS 2.x plugin using the `vue create <my-plugin-name>` and the `vue-cli-plugin-p11n` plugin. I have a directory structure that consists of a `dist/` directory with a few compiled JS files and a main `src/` folder containing my components.

I'd like to use these components within Nuxt JS 2.4.x.

I've created a `plugins/LesForm.js` plugin, and have added `'@/plugins/LesForm'` to my array of plugins within `nuxt.config.js`.

My plugin file consists of:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import LesForm from 'LesForm'

Vue.use(LesForm)
```

I'm then trying to import the plugin with it's component into a page by doing: `<LesForm></LesForm>` within my page.

I initially get the error of:

`Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`, but adding the following to my script tag of a page seems to remove that error, but this doesn't seem right?

```
<script>

import LesForm from 'LesForm'

export default {
  components: {
    LesForm
  }
}

</script>
```

without this, my page breaks, and adding it I get: `Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.` as an error with no sign of my Vue plugin that I've made with some markup.

I'm using the Vue Cli service to build my plugin via NPM.

Attached is a screenshot of my plugin directory structure:

[image]

Comment: Does your `Plugin` perform a `Vue.component('les-form', '/path/to/component')`? If not, then this makes sense.

Comment: I don't think so, is this something I add into the plugin, or into the plugin file within Nuxt JS

Comment: Not entirely sure... `Vue.component('les-form', '/src/components/HelloWorld.vue')` doesn't seem to work, I've added this to the `LesForm.js` plugin file within Nuxt JS. is my linking wrong? do I have to link through node_modules within my source here.